# What is the logic of demangling?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a code like this. The code is working
I understand that the code prints 'm' because of demangling (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html)

But why does compiler print 'm' for `size_t`?
What is the logic of mapping ('i' --> `int` // it's clear, but why 'm' --> `size_t`)

```
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    size_t i = 5;
    cout << "Type: " << typeid(i).name() << '\n'; // Type: m
}
```

Comment: I don't see any demangling taking place in your code.

Comment: I think you confuse mangling with demangling. Mangling is taking user facing names like `int` and converting them to ABI names like `i` and demangling is the reverse process where you get ABI names like `i` and convert them back to user friendly names like `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the [itanium ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling-builtin) you'll see that all the unsigned types use the next letter in the alphabet after their signed equivalent (except `char`). `int` is `i`, `unsigned int` is `j`. `long` is `l` and `unsigned long` is `m`. As `size_t` isn't an itanium type it's represented by `unsigned long` and therefore `m`.

The assigned letters are essentially arbitrary so though there is some logic to their assignment they're not really important exactly what they are. They're an implementation detail and are platform specific, if you need to know what they mean use a demangler like `c++filt`, http://demangler.com/ or [abi::__cxa_demangle](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html)

Answer (score 1):

> But why does compiler print 'm' for size_t?

Because `size_t` is an `unsigned long` *on this platform* and the letter `m` represents `unsigned long` *in this compiler on this platform*.

> What is the logic of mapping ('i' --> int // it's clear, but why 'm' --> size_t)

There is no "logic", there are just rules laid out what letter is what type. See https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling-builtin .